# Why do I get "Unable to locate package errors when attempting to install packages via apt-get on Kali Linux 2020.4?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I  have a VM with Kali Linux 2020.4. I'm running into issues trying to install packages via apt-get

When I run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package gnome-do
```

This is what my sources.list looks like:
[image: sources.list]

I tried to update my source.list according to search results from google on the issue. Unless I'm missing something, sources.list looks right to me.... I've done an update and rebooted the VM; still the same issue.

I tried installing "bum" as well, but still same error.

Is there a step I'm missing here?

Thanks, JohnB

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Gnome-do (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Do)

> GNOME Do (often referred to as Do) is a free and open-source
> application launcher for Linux originally created by David Siegel,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Do)
> and currently maintained by Alex Launi. Like other application
> launchers, it allows searching for applications and files, but it also
> allows specifying actions to perform on search results. GNOME Do
> allows for quick finding of miscellaneous artifacts of GNOME
> environment (applications, Evolution and Pidgin contacts, Firefox
> bookmarks, Rhythmbox artists and albums, and so on) and execute the
> basic actions on them (launch, open, email, chat, play, etc.).[2]
>
> While it is designed primarily for the GNOME desktop, it works in
> other desktop environments, such as KDE.

Did you uninstall Xfce and install the Gnome Desktop environment?

Also if you want / need Gnome tools in general, consider using Ubuntu (or variant) instead of Kali. That will likely work much better.

Simple, self-contained Gnome apps from Installlion tend to work fine, but if you need the complete Gnome environment, try a Gnome based Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[gnome-do](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/gnome-do) has been removed from Kali Linux since 2018. Your only options are building from source, mixing in packages from vanilla Debian (generally a bad idea) or using a different distro that is designed for normal users such as Ubuntu (which is recommended for Linux beginners anyways).